# Interesting problem about books in library turned into an array problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, contest-math

[image: Problem text]

My last post got closed because of a lack of information, so I added more info, but I didn't know how to put it on review again, so I just made this new question with more info.

This is a MO competition problem, and I have seen some proofs with weird constructions, but I was wondering whether it has some more motivated proof.

Here is my reasoning and the way I might have turned the problem into a more approachable one:

The main idea is to look at how many books there are that are on a shelf with less than or equal to $i$
books. Then if we find $i$
for which the difference of that value between the $2$ configurations (before and after adding new shelves) is maximized, we know that some books from shelves with more than $i$
books have to be set to those with less or equal, and the amount of books is equal to that difference. Array $d$ is the difference in number of books that are on shelves with exactly $i$ books between $2$ configurations.

I apologize for bad wording, it's hard for me to concisely phrase my reasoning for this problem, and that's why I initially only posted the derived problem without the background.

Anyway, here's the problem:

*$d_i$ is the difference in number of books that are on shelves with exactly i
books between 2 configurations*

let $(d_1,d_2,d_3,...,d_m)$
be an array of integers s.t.

$d_1+d_2+d_3+...+d_m=k,k>0$

and

$d_1+2d_2+3d_3+...+md_m=0$

What is the lower bound for the maximum element of a set

{$d_1,d_1+2d_2,d_1+2d_2+3d_3,...,d_1+2d_2+3d_3+...+md_m$}?

Comment: Your first equation doesn't make sense. The number of shelves has increased by $k$. The number of books has not changed, and so the sum of their difference is 0. Similarly, your second statement doesn't have a sensible interpretation. $\quad$ What you might mean is: "$d_i$ is the difference in number of SHELVES with $i$ books". In which case, see my solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-idea solution, which doesn't involve any "weird construction" (at least to me).

For each library book $l$, we label it with the weights $ ( \frac{1}{ a_l}, \frac{1}{b_l})$, where it has $a_l$ books on it's shelf initially, and $b_l$ books on it's shelf eventually. By double counting, $ \sum \frac{1}{a_l} = n$ and $\sum \frac{1}{b_l} = n+k$, the number of shelves.

Let $ c_l = \frac{1}{b_l} - \frac{1}{a_l}$. The problem is equivalent to showing that the number of positive $c_l$ is at least $k+1$.

Notice that

1. $1 > c_l $.
2. $ k = \sum c_l \leq \sum_{c_l > 0 } c_l $.

Clearly, to get to a sum of at least $k$, we need at least $k+1$ positive numbers that are each strictly less than 1, . Hence we are done.

---

Furthermore, this can be accomplished by having $n+k$ books, where initially there are $n-1$ shelves with 1 book each and $1$ shelf with $k+1$ books, and eventually there are $n+k$ shelves with 1 book each. Hence, this bound is tight.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an answer that is effectively the same as Calvin’s (and motivated by his), but that might feel a little more discoverable.

For each of the $n$ original shelves, draw a pie chart with equal slices for each book. A shelf with one book gets a one-slice pie chart, a shelf with 8 books gets an 8-slice pie chart, etc. The total area of all the slices is $n$ pies.

After the books are moved, draw pie charts again for each of the $n+k$ shelves. Now the total area is $n+k$ pies.

The increase from $n$ to $n+k$ is due to the fact that some books had their slice size increase. Some might have had their slice size go down, too, but the total slice size over all books increased by $k$.

A book's original slice size is positive, and its final slice size is at most 1, so a given book’s slice-size increase is less than 1.

For the total increase to be $k$, more than $k$ books must have seen increases in their pie slice size, and these are the privileged books.